# Can <beans> have a definition of <bean> inside when being used with profile?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I am getting this error when deploying my web application on weblogic server.

```
:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'beans'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":description, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"]}' is expected.
```

This is the xml file I am loading the beans from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <beans profile="dev">

    <!-- Define component scan targets --> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sheidaei.chnlsales.web.service" />

    <bean id="eWUser" class="com.sheidaei.chnlsales.web.model.EWUser" scope="session">
        <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
    </bean>
 </beans>
 </beans>
```

Any ideas on why am I getting this error? It seems that it is expecting something other than profile at that point. Can't I use profile after beans? I am using Spring 3.2 and according to spring you can use profiles after Spring 3.1 http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/

This is the stack trace:

```
<Jun 27, 2014 1:28:43 PM EDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application 'ToolIntWeb [Version=1.0]'.>
<Jun 27, 2014 1:28:43 PM EDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: :org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'beans'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":descr
iption, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/
schema/beans"]}' is expected.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:417)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Jun 27, 2014 1:28:43 PM EDT> <Error> <Console> <BEA-240003> <Console encountered the following error weblogic.application.ModuleException: :org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content
 was found starting with element 'beans'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":description, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":
alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"]}' is expected.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:417)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3182)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1806)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:705)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:235)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
        at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryDocumentBuilder.parse(RegistryDocumentBuilder.java:163)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1872)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3153)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:43)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of "spring-beans-3.0.xsd", use "spring-beans.xsd" in "xsi:schemaLocation".

As a best practice, do not specify version number in Spring schema references. Spring will automatically pick the highest version from project dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing the incorrect xsd version. 3.0 does not contain the 'profile' attribute. General practice is to leave the version number off of the XSD definition as when spring loads it will load the version bundled in your spring jar.

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting a `<beans>` element inside another `<beans>` element. Your XSD declaration references a versioned schema (3.0) which does not allow nested `<beans>` elements:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
```

According to the documentation you linked:

> *spring-beans-3.1.xsd has been updated to allow this nesting.*

So you should use the 3.1 schema, not the 3.0 one.